# Example async dart code not working

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Every example of async code I have tried in Dart, mostly from their site does not seem to work for me.

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  var socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  print(socket.runtimeType);
  socket.write('Hello, World!');
}
```

Example code from their [cookbook](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-vm/dart-by-example#sockets)

And it throws me

```
error: line 3 pos 1: unexpected token 'main'
main() async {
```

I think its looking for a return type for the function? But I can't find any kind of documentmentation where you can tell what it is looking for, thanks for the help!

Comment: My dart says its version is `1.5.3` I run the install as `choco install dart-sdk -version 1.18.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart asynchrony support (async, await etc.) came in version 1.9. You need to update your SDK.

Presumably your update did not work. Try `choco upgrade dart-sdk`. Or you may have to uninstall then re-install the latest version.

Comment: Yup, thanks I ended up using the unofficial install method and it seemed to isntall the correct version, I installed it like yesterday, and I checked the version file in the dart-sdk folder and it said 1.18.2, not sure what messed up, thanks for the clarification on version numbers

Comment: You may have had the current sdk *and* an older one installed, The older one being run when you invoked `dart.exe`. Which is why`dart.exe --version` printed `1.5.3` even though the version file you checked indicated 1.18.2.